# Power button behaviour. onPause > onResume > onPause being called

Tags: android, andengine

When using the power button, the engine calls the onPause(), then onResume() and then onPause() again for the 2nd time.
I'm sure this isn't normal behavior. Could it be the device I'm testing on? 
I've stripped Both functions down to default with just the super calls inside and this still occurs.

Comment: are you locking the screen, then unlocking the screen?

Comment: I can take that question a few ways. But i think you mean am i hitting the power button then unlocking the screen.
When the app is open and in focus, when i hit the power button it calls onPause, onResume then onPause again while the screen is still black. In short, I'm just locking the screen.
Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The framework decides when onResume/onPause shall be called, It does not matter if you overwrite the lifecycle callbacks or not. You can't change the system behaviour and yes, it might be the device you test on.